# Squirrelmail autoforwarding incoming mails

Tags: email, ubuntu, plugins, squirrelmail

I want to make squirrelmail automatically forward every email that I receive without having to login and do it myself. I have have found 2 plugins from the site but none of them seem to be working (autoresponder, local_autorespond_forward)
I tried to do that by myself straight from the code but the messages are decoded.I am new to squirrelmail so I would like some help please. It is installed in a ubuntu server.

This is the problem i get with autoresponder
There was a problem connecting to your FTP server:  "cannot log in to localhost".  Please contact your support department.
Local_autorespond_forward plugin does not show any option when i go change its properties from the options.

Thanks